# Find and Replace Text in file if exists / Append if not exists using Perl

Tags: perl, replace, append

I need a Perl script that open and searches a file for a specific string for example (foo1 = 10) ,if that exists it should replace it with (foo1 = 5) if it doesn't exist it should append it to the end of the file

Thanks

**Update**

This is my code thus far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
my $fileName   = $ARGV[0];
my $searchStr  = $ARGV[1];
my $replaceStr = $ARGV[2];
print( "\nFilename:",     $fileName,   "\n" );
print( "Search String:",  $searchStr,  "\n" );
print( "Replace String:", $replaceStr, "\n\n" );
open( FILE, $fileName );
  || die("Cannot Open File");
my (@fcont) = <FILE>;
close FILE;
open( FOUT, ">$fileName" ) || die("Cannot Open File");
foreach $line (@fcont) {
    $line =~ s/$searchStr/$replaceStr/g;
}
close FOUT;
```

I just need a counter that counts the replace times, if it equals zero then append to end of file.

anyone can help in that would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm sorry, but you won't easily find people that do the coding for you here. Please show what you have tried and then feel free to ask any questions that remain here.

Comment: If the file fits in your memory: Read it into an array, close the file, reopen it for writing so that it gets truncated, iterate through your array and print the line as is unless it fits some regex in which case, print whatever you want to replace the line with.

Comment: The thing is i am not a perl developer , i am a C# developer but i am trying to execute that perl script on a linux machine ,so it's not doing coding for me , if you need assistance in c#  i can help but not in perl which i know nothing about

Comment: anyhow i did manage to do that 

#!/usr/bin/env perl                                                                                             

my $fileName=$ARGV[0];
my $searchStr=$ARGV[1];
my $replaceStr=$ARGV[2];

print ("\nFilename:",$fileName,"\n");
print ("Search String:",$searchStr,"\n");
print ("Replace String:",$replaceStr,"\n\n");

open(FILE,$fileName); || die("Cannot Open File");
my(@fcont) = <FILE>;
close FILE;

open(FOUT,">$fileName") || die("Cannot Open File");
foreach $line (@fcont) {
    $line =~ s/$searchStr/$replaceStr/g;
    
}
close FOUT;

Comment: i just need a counter that counts the replace times ,if it equals zero then append to end of file ,anyone can help in that would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If you're not a Perl programmer and you want to write a Perl program then either a) learn Perl or b) hire a Perl programmer. By the way, did you know that C# runs on Linux - http://www.mono-project.com

Comment: it's a script with a couple of lines , if u don't want to help fine ,just don't instead of posting that silly comments , i am using SSH.net library to invoke commands on the linux machine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Straight from perlfaq5 - [`How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change%2c-delete%2c-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file%2c-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file%3f)

All things being equal, I'd probably use [`Tie::File`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/File.html) for this particular problem.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;

my $fileName   = $ARGV[0];
my $searchStr  = $ARGV[1];
my $replaceStr = $ARGV[2];

tie my @fcont, "Tie::File", $fileName;

my $count;
for (@fcont) {
    $count++ if s/\Q$searchStr/$replaceStr/;
}
push @fcont, $replaceStr if ! $count;
```

Comment: Your welcome.  Btw, to get the most benefit from StackOverflow, always show work/code when posting a question, and state the specific difficulties that you're having.  When you first posted, I gave you the link only solution since you didn't show your work.  But you posting the code made it so that I was willing to show you how `Tie::File` would cover this problem.  Anyway, welcome to SO.